# if(Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey("isLogin")) is getting null exception in Xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin.ios

I want to store some user data locally in my cross platform app. When I try to check, get or store data into application from xamarin.ios project. It's getting null exception. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: are you calling this AFTER Xamarin Forms has been Initialized?

Comment: How do you store and retrieve data? Can you share some code?